# Stress Testing needs to done on tableau portal

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing

1. Tableau version just got upgraded from 9 to 10 . There are 500 reports which i need to test in v10 .
2. My requirement is - if 50+ users access the same report at same time , is there any impact , basically stress testing .
3. For that , i need information regarding any "open source tool or firefox plugin" which can create a lot of dummy users and access the report at same time .
4. i read JMeter carries out the same , but i am looking for a tool/plugin which is easy to use and requires little or no programming. 
   Kindly suggest how can i achieve it .

Answer (score 0):

You can find the up-to-date list of free and open source load testing tools [here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php), the most advanced tools where no programming knowledge required are [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) and [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/), both provide record and replay functionality.

---

Given your "50 users" requirement you can also consider [LoadRunner](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/loadrunner-load-testing/index.html?jumpid=va_uwxy6ce9tr) or [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/), the first one assumes C language knowledge for advanced scripting, but it is pretty good in replaying tests recorded via browser, the latter one has "FollowMe" mode when a number of virtual users repeat you online actions, the solution is available as a [Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en), see [A New Script-Less Era of Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/new-script-less-era-performance-testing-0) article for details.

Answer (score 0):

Let's be realistic.  Humans are chaotic instruments.  They arrive and depart at different times from a system.  They are not governed by a clock tick.

The odds of any two users hitting the same report at exactly the same instant are pretty close to zero.  Even looking at the largest shopping days of the year, with the chaotic nature of when someone checks out the number of collisions of same business process, same section of code, same time come down to less than a dozen for very large user sets.  Plus, if you have 50 users who all need the same report then you are better off batching the creation of the report and having it either (a) placed in a portal where users hit a static copy or (b) automating an email of the report to the fifty users.